# Creating *.csv with Field name and Field type from feature class using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, export, csv

I would like to create tool that will be generate *.csv with information about feature class (field_name, type).
You can find my code:

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
dataset_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Report_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
fields = arcpy.ListFields()

for field in fields:
    print("{0} is a type of {1} with a length of {2}"
          .format(field.name, field.type, field.length))
```

[image]

Could you advise?

Comment: Apart from `ListFields` missing the dataset parameter, what is your question?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I now that I can put path for dataset, but I would like put here dataset_name as in script parameters.   fields = arcpy.ListFields('dataset_name') - is it right, if I will put like this?

Comment: Yes, but without the quotes: `fields = arcpy.ListFields(dataset_name)`

Answer (score 0):

This script solved my task:

```
import arcpy
import os
import xlwt
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
Dataset_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Report_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
fields = arcpy.ListFields(Dataset_name)
wb = xlwt.Workbook() 
ws = wb.add_sheet('Test') 

ws.write(0, 0, "Field") 
ws.write(0, 1, "Type")
row = 1

for field in fields:
  print field.name, field.length, field.type
  ws.write(row, 0, field.name)
  ws.write(row, 1, field.type)
  row += 1
```